# PHP library compatible with Google Workspace's (G suite) SSO by SAML2.0?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, onelogin

I need to make my web application compatible with Google Workspace's (G suite) saml2.0 SSO.

- My web app -> SP
- Google workspace -> IdP

Is this onelogin's library suitable to achieve that?
https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml

Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Questons asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic. So are questions asking for opinions. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time familiarizing yourself with the [help] pages to learn how the site works before posting.

Answer (score 0):

onelogin/php-saml is compatible with most SAML2 Identity Providers.  If you use symfony in your web application hslavich/OneloginSamlBundle might be needed.

It is well supported and has regular updates so it would certainly be a suitable method to add SAML2 support